# Would Rewriting It Using Regex Shorten/Beautify The Code?

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm, parsing, parameters

The problem is a little challenging because I want to code it using `std::regex` believing it would be easier to read and faster to write.

But it seems that I can only code it one way (shown below).

Somehow my mind could not see the solution using `std::regex`.

How would you code it?

Would using `std::regex_search` do the job?

```
/*
input: data coming in:
/product/country/123456/city/7890/g.json

input: url parameter format:
/product/country/<id1:[0-9]+>/city/<id2:[0-9]+>/g.json

output:
std::vector<std::string> urlParams

sample output:
urlParams[0] = "123456"
urlParams[1] = "7890"
*/

bool ParseIt(const char *path, const char* urlRoute, std::vector<std::string> *urlParams)
{
   const DWORD BUFSZ = 2000;
   char buf[BUFSZ];
   DWORD dwSize = strlen(urlRoute);
   urlParams.clear();

   int j = 0;
   int i = 0;
   bool good = false;
   for (i = 0; i < dwSize; i++)
   {
       char c1 = path[j++];
       char c2 = urlRoute[i];
       if (c2 == '<')
       {
           good = true;
           while (c2 != '/')
           { 
               i++;
               c2 = urlRoute[i];
           }
           int k = 0;
           memset(buf, 0, BUFSZ);
           while (c1 != '/')
           {
               buf[k++] = c1;
               c1 = path[j++];
           }
           urlParams->push_back(_strdup(buf));
           int b = 1;
       }
       if (c1 != c2)
       {
           return false;
       }
       if (c2 != '<')
       {
           if (c1 == c1)
           {

           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
        }

    }

    if (dwSize == i && good)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's absolutely what regexes are for, about fifteen lines of code when you are finished.

Comment: regex would make a much cleaner code indeed but I can't promise you it would be faster though

Comment: An old miss-quote:   "I have a problem, part of which I can solve with a Regex".    "Now you have two problems."

Answer (score 0):

The easiest one I've found (might not be the best but should work with your input data) is

```
std::string subject("/product/country/123456/city/7890/g.json");
std::regex re("/(\d+)/city/(\d+)/");
std::smatch match;
std::regex_search(subject, match, re);
```

It matches two values per line. The `/` matches for the slash at the beginning/end and the `()` does the capture. You will have to convert it from the string type though.

Comment: Did you test that? I would have thought that `//` would match two slashes. If they were backslashes (`\\`), it would be different.

Comment: I typed this one out of memory so I guess it's wrong. I tend to confuse the syntax since it's always similar